# Getting unexpected error when using structure type

Tags: arrays, scala, types, structural-typing

I'm new to Scala programming, so please bear with me if it's a silly question. I was expecting the following code to work, since `a` has a `mkString` method.

```
val a = "abc".toCharArray

case class A[T: {def mkString(): String}](i: T) {
  val s = i.mkString
}

A(a)
```

But it gives the following error:

> Error:(3, 16) AnyRef{def mkString(): String} does not take type
>   parameters case class A[T: {def mkString(): String}](i: T)
>
> Error:(4, 14) value mkString is not a member of type parameter T   val
>   s = i.mkString

I'm using Scala 2.11.6.

Any help will be really appreciated! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least three mistakes there:

1. It should be `<:`, not `:`. The structural type is not a typeclass.
2. `def mkString(): String` is not the same as `def mkString: String`.
3. raw JVM arrays know nothing about convenient scala methods like `mkString`. You need a `WrappedArray` for that.

This here works:

```
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
val a = "abc".toCharArray

import collection.mutable.WrappedArray

case class A[T <: { def mkString: String }](i: T){
  val s = i.mkString
}

A(a: WrappedArray[Char])
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey! Just a quick question, what's the purporse of `import scala.language.reflectiveCalls`?

Comment: @BubbleBubbleBubbleGut Preventing the compiler from throwing warnings at me and suggesting to import `scala.language.reflectiveCalls' ;)

Comment: Ohhh got it! Thank you!!

Comment: Hey Andrew, if you got time could you take at look at the other question that I just posted? Would really appreciate it you could help me with that too

Answer (score 2):

The type bounds `[A : B]` is a shorthand way of saying there exists an instance of the typeclass `B` for type `A`, so these are equivalent:

```
def foo[A : B]: C

def foo[A](implicit b: B[A]): C
```

The syntax you're probably looking for is `[A <: B]`, which means `A` must be a subclass of `B`.

But then you have the issue that `mkString` isn't actually in the `Array` class; it's defined in `ArrayOps` (with an implicit conversion from `Array`) as described in the documentation:

> This member is added by an implicit conversion from Array[T] to
>   ArrayOps[T] performed by method genericArrayOps in scala.Predef.

You can work around that with:

```
val a = "abc".toCharArray

case class A[T](i: T)(implicit conv: T => {def mkString: String}) {
  val s = conv(i).mkString
}

A(a)
```